# Apache Spark: How to allocate more memory to driver in Local Master mode?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, driver

I try to run spark application locally on my computer.

I set master local[*].

```
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.master("local[*]")
.getOrCreate()
```

I use the next command to run my application:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 4g solver.jar
```

But when I go to Spark UI, I see that memory that was allocated to drive is only 2.2Gb.

[image]

How can I allocate more memory to my driver?

Comment: What do you see on Spark Web UI? I mean total memory available? Please add a screenshot of that as well, if possible.

Comment: What you see is Spark-managed memory, ~60% of total heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `--driver-memory 4g` is the correct way to increase the memory.

on sparkUI, Storage Memory is displayed. Max of storage memory is calculated using: `(JVM Heap Space - 300 MB) * 0.6`

In your case: ((4*1024 - 300) * 0.6) / 1024 = 2.2 GiB

more details here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview